# Avoid boilerpate of tagless final in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tagless-final

The following code shows a tagless final lambda typeclass and an evaluation instance:

```hs
class Lambda (repr :: * -> *) where
    int :: Int -> repr Int
    add :: repr Int -> repr Int -> repr Int
    lambda :: forall a b. (repr a -> repr b) -> repr (a -> b)
    apply :: forall a b. repr (a -> b) -> repr a -> repr b

-- eval
instance Lambda Identity where
    int = Identity
    add x y = Identity $ runIdentity x + runIdentity y
    lambda f = Identity $ \x -> runIdentity (f (Identity x))
    apply (Identity f) (Identity x) = Identity $ f x
```

But there are lots of boilerplate of plugging `Identity` and `runIdentity`. How can I avoid them?

I tried to use the type family as following:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Lambda f where
    type Repr f a
    int :: Int -> Repr f Int
    add :: Repr f Int -> Repr f Int -> Repr f Int
    lambda :: forall a b. (Repr f a -> Repr f b) -> Repr f (a -> b)
    apply :: forall a b. Repr f (a -> b) -> Repr f a -> Repr f b
    
data Eval
instance Lambda Eval where
    type Repr Eval a = a
    int = id
    add = (+)
    lambda = id
    apply f = f
```

I have two questions:

1. Why is the following declaration incurs an error?

```
exp1 :: Lambda f => Repr f Int
exp1 = int 1
```

with error:

```
app/Main.hs:63:8: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type: Repr f Int
                  with actual type: Repr f0 Int
      NB: ‘Repr’ is a non-injective type family
      The type variable ‘f0’ is ambiguous
    • In the expression: int 1
      In an equation for ‘exp1’: exp1 = int 1
    • Relevant bindings include
        exp1 :: Repr f Int (bound at app/Main.hs:63:1)
   |
63 | exp1 = int 1
   |        ^^^^^
```

2. Is it a good practice to write the tagless final with the type family?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using "safe coercions":

```
import Data.Coerce

instance Lambda Identity where
    int = Identity
    add = coerce ((+) @Int)
    lambda f = coerce f
    apply f x = coerce f x
```

Intuitively `coerce` is a tool that will automagically apply `Identity` and `runIdentity` as needed to make the expression to type-check. Note that it will usually fail to work if you use it on a polymorphic function since type inference won't be able to work as usual: that's why we wrote `coerce ((+) @Int)` above.

More in detail, you can convince yourself that `coerce` is enough in the above cases if you compare types before and after coercion, and observe that it only differs from `Identity` being used at some points.

```
add = coerce ((+) @Int)
-- before :: Int -> Int -> Int
-- after  :: Identity Int -> Identity Int -> Identity Int

lambda f = coerce f
-- before :: Identity a -> Identity b
-- after  :: Identity (a -> b)

apply f x = coerce f x
-- f before :: Identity (a -> b)
--   after  :: Identity a -> Identity b
```

Anyway, using type families instead as you did looks good to me. Regarding your question

> 1. Why is the following declaration incurs an error?
>
>    ```
>    exp1 :: Lambda f => Repr f Int
>    exp1 = int 1
>    ```

This raises an error because the call of `int` is ambiguous. That could be the `int` defined in the constraint `Lambda f`, but it could also be the `int` defined in `Lambda Eval` (i.e., we do not use the constraint in scope). Note that it is possible that two instances have the same `Repr` because type families do not have to be injective, so the ambiguity arises. For example:

```
data Eval
instance Lambda Eval where
    type Repr Eval a = a
    int = id
    ...
data Eval2
instance Lambda Eval2 where
    type Repr Eval a = a
    int = (+10)
    ...

test :: Repr Eval Int -- AKA Int
test = int 7 -- is it 7 or 17 ? It's ambiguous, so we reject it.
```

To disambiguate, use `ScopedTypeVariables` and `TypeApplications`.

```
exp1 :: forall f. Lambda f => Repr f Int
exp1 = int @f 1   -- use the int from the constraint
```

> 2. Is it a good practice to write the tagless final with the type family?

Here I must confess that I'm not too familiar with the tagless final approach, so I can't give you a precise answer. I can only state that it does not look wrong in my eye.